# How to query for a specific day of the month in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Trying to automate a query that will pull data for the current month where the day of the month (in the date field) is >= the 15th. Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax to achieve this?

I want to be able to run this query each month without having to change anything. So in May, it would automatically pull any item where the date was >= 5/15/16. In June, it would pull items where the date was >= 6/15/16. And so on.....

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This will allow you to use any indexes you have on your `date_field` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_field >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) + INTERVAL '14' DAY
AND    date_field <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 );
```

Comment: why use "interval" there? That goes with timestamp arithmetic, not date arithmetic.

Comment: @Boneist That is incorrect - it can be used with both dates and timestamps. Try `SELECT SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL;`. I just use it to explicitly state that the number `14` is `14 days` so that there is no confusion during code reviews as to what the number means and the context in which it is being used.

Comment: huh, in that case I stand corrected! I hadn't ever considered using intervals with dates, believing that it would cause implicit conversion of the date into a timestamp. Using DUMP() I can see that that isn't the case. Thanks for the learning opportunity! *{:-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks like it will work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @tgall0163 If this or any other answer has solved your problem then you can click on the tick mark below the voting buttons (left of the answer) to accept it and indicate the answer has resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your date/time fields are of type timestamp you can do

```
select x from <your_table>
where EXTRACT(DAY from <timestamp field>) >=15
and EXTRACT(MONTH from <timestamp field>) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
and EXTRACT(YEAR from <timestamp field>)  = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: This works but you if you have an index on the date column then the index will not be used (unless you put function-based indexes on each `EXTRACT(XYZ FROM column_name)`).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is something like:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, to_date('01/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 2 id, to_date('10/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 3 id, to_date('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 4 id, to_date('15/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 5 id, to_date('16/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 6 id, to_date('30/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 7 id, to_date('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual)
select *
from   sample_data
where  dt >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 14
and    dt < last_day(trunc(sysdate)) + 1;

        ID DT        
---------- ----------
         4 15/06/2016
         5 16/06/2016
         6 30/06/2016
```

(If you wanted rows with any date greater than the 15th of the current month, then remove the last predicate in the where clause.)